Alphawalet is moderate not transfering my founds
I am using ALPHAWALET, and I tried to withdraw my funds, and it's been moderating for days. Some help centers are asking for a deposit of 2500usdt to withdraw my funds. I don't know what to do. I put 2540USDT by mistake and then they told me to deposit aging but 2500USDT because the program can't recognize
